# Could not find generator refinerycms-news engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I am trying to generate refinery-new in my refinerycms and facing following error...

```
$ rails generate refinerycms-news

Could not find generator refinerycms-news
```

I have already installed refinerycms-news by using this command

```
gem install refinerycms-news
```

i have already installed follow gems but i dont know what is the actual problem :(

```
   $ bundle list
   Gems included by the bundle:
   * abstract (1.0.0)
   * actionmailer (3.0.11)
   * actionpack (3.0.11)
   * activemodel (3.0.11)
   * activerecord (3.0.11)
   * activeresource (3.0.11)
   * activesupport (3.0.11)
   * acts_as_indexed (0.7.7)
   * arel (2.0.10)
   * awesome_nested_set (2.1.2)
   * babosa (0.3.6)
   * bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
   * builder (2.1.2)
   * bundler (1.0.21)
   * devise (1.4.9)
   * dragonfly (0.9.10)
   * erubis (2.6.6)
   * friendly_id_globalize3 (3.2.1.6)
   * globalize3 (0.1.0)
   * i18n (0.5.0)
   * json (1.6.5)
   * mail (2.2.19)
   * mime-types (1.17.2)
   * orm_adapter (0.0.6)
   * polyglot (0.3.3)
   * rack (1.2.5)
   * rack-cache (1.1)
   * rack-mount (0.6.14)
   * rack-test (0.5.7)
   * rails (3.0.11)
   * railties (3.0.11)
   * rake (0.9.2.2)
   * rdoc (3.12)
   * refinerycms (1.0.9)
   * refinerycms-authentication (1.0.9)
   * refinerycms-base (1.0.9)
   * refinerycms-core (1.0.9)
   * refinerycms-dashboard (1.0.9)
   * refinerycms-events (1.0)
   * refinerycms-generators (1.0.4)
   * refinerycms-i18n (1.0.0)
   * refinerycms-images (1.0.9)
   * refinerycms-pages (1.0.9)
   * refinerycms-news (1.2.0)
   * refinerycms-resources (1.0.9)
   * refinerycms-settings (1.0.9)
   * routing-filter (0.3.0)
   * seo_meta (1.1.1)
   * sqlite3 (1.3.5)
   * thor (0.14.6)
   * treetop (1.4.10)
   * truncate_html (0.5.1)
   * tzinfo (0.3.31)
   * warden (1.0.6)
   * will_paginate (3.0.3)
```

please help me

Comment: problem resolved i just removed # (sign) in my Gemfile which i located in my root app folder.

    '# Specify additional Refinery CMS Engines here (all optional):
    # gem 'refinerycms-inquiries',    '~> 1.0'
    **gem "refinerycms-news",         '~> 1.2'**
    # gem 'refinerycms-blog',         '~> 1.6'
    # gem 'refinerycms-page-images',  '~> 1.0''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually  `#` in ruby is a comment. all code after # will not run 
So when you remove `#` bundler install refinerycms-news too